# how to call public sub from private shared sub vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

this is for writing data to same file multithreading

```
Dim _readWriteLock As ReaderWriterLockSlim = New ReaderWriterLockSlim

    Private Sub writedatatofile(ByVal s As String)
        ' Set Status to Locked

        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock()
        Try
            ' Append text to the file
            Dim sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("textfile.txt")
            sw.WriteLine(s)
            sw.Close()
        Finally
            ' Release lock
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

this is for getting asynchronous response

```
Private Shared Sub GetResponseCallback(ByVal asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
      Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult),  _
       HttpWebResponse)

writedatatofile(Response.Headers.Tostring)

End Sub
```

whene i call writedatatofile from GetresponseCallback i get this error : **Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class**

how can i write safety multithreads to same text file from asynchronous response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call an Instance method from a Shared (static) method. You are basically saying, "I want to call a method that operates on a particular instance of an object from a method that doesn't care about object instances" - so how would the Shared method be able to do that?

You need to change `GetResponseCallback` to instance (removed the Shared modifier).

Comment: And writedatatofile is not public BTW, as mentioned in the question title.

Comment: @abhitalks It seems like both of these methods are in the same class, so it doesn't matter that it isn't public. Public methods can call Private methods if they are in the same type.

Comment: yes i tried it but it was begingetrequeststream too so  i should remove the shared modifier too ! thanks